# ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

This is my table. id expected as Primary Key and auto filled

```
mysql> DESCRIBE test_table
-> ;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| phone | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I INSERT data this way

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test_table (name, phone) VALUES ('Nikita', '26908050');
```

It returns error, that id doesn't have Default value.

```
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

How I can tell MySQL that id must start with 0 and increese each time something is added to test_table?

Comment: Instead of using `DESCRIBE` you should post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table`.

Answer (score 6):

The field `id` requires the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute. Otherwise, it is undefined and that is what the error message says.

[See here for full documentation and example.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

If you want to modify an already existing table, use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table CHANGE id id INT(8) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 2):

I´ve resolved this problem editting the mysql config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

find: 
[mysqld]

and type under it

```
sql_mode =
```

so, save the file and restart the mysql server